# Find total file size of a disk

Tags: filesystems, rsync, ntfs

I have a corrupted NTFS volume. I ran `rsync` to copy everything from it, which reported a total # bytes transferred at the end.

What's another tool I can use to verify the total # bytes on the disk against `rsync`'s reported # of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

If the disk is mounted I typically use `du` and `df` to determine the size of the disk and the size of the files/directories on this disk/partition.

```
$ df -h /path/to/dir

-or-

$ du -sh /path/to/dir

-or-

$ du -sh --apparent-size /path/to/dir
```

#### Examples

*df*

```
$ df -h /home
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home  402G  158G  224G  42% /home
```

*du*

```
$ du -sh --apparent-size /home/saml/bin
32M /home/saml/bin
```